# Catching Scrolled event stops RowSelected event (UITableView,Xamarin,MonoTouch)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a UITableView and I am using a subclass of UITableViewSource to control the data as in the default master-detail app setup.

When I click on a row I get a RowSelected event and all is well.

If I catch the Scrolled event on the list however I get the scrolled events but I stop getting the RowSelected callback.

```
TableView.Source = _dataSource = new DataSource (this);

// STOPS RowSelected callback from being called
TableView.Scrolled += (sender, e) => {
};
```

Has anyone experienced this or have a work around so that I can detect the RowSelected event as well as trapping the scroll event?

My intention is to have a 'load more' detection so that when the list is scrolled to the end I automatically load more items form a web service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK Found the solution!

I am still new to iOS development and Xamarin but the following page mentions that '**you aren't supposed to mix Objective-C delegates with C# events**'.

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6136/uitableviewsource-scrolled-is-not-fired-in-debug-mode-on-iphone-device

I don't fully understand how Objective-C delegates work but I suspect by overriding that even I was somehow changing the internal event handler?

To trap the scrolled event UITableViewSource has a helpful method called 'Scrolled' just needs overriding to catch the event!